# Date::Manip Not Installing

Tags: perl, date

I keep getting error messages when trying to install the [`Date::Manip`](http://search.cpan.org/~sbeck/Date-Manip-6.45/lib/Date/Manip.pod) module. Any Perl experts know what I can try? 
The command I'm trying is

```
perl -MCPAN -e "install Date::Manip"
```

Perl version is 5.20 and the version of the Date::Manip it keeps trying to install is 6.45, but it comes back with "Make had some problems" and "No such file in archive". It does prompt me to manually install the file, but i have no clue on how to do that. Here's what it says...

```
Could not find file 'sulbeck@heather.osg.ufl.edu.2024:1399465428' in memory at C:\Strawberry\perl\lib/CPAN/Tarzip.pm line 408.

Making symbolic link 'C:\STRAWB~1\cpan\build\tmp-3576\Date-Manip6.45\lib\Date\Manip\.#Changes6.pod' to 'sulbeck@heather.osg.ufl.edu.2024:1399465428' failed at C:\Strawberry\perl\lib/CPAN/Tarzip.pm line 408.

Could not untar with Archive::Tar  SBECK/Date-Manip-6.45.tar.gz

Had problems unarchiving. please build manually. Stopping: 'install' failed for 'Date:Manip
```

Comment: Something a little strange is going on with that module.  It's currently not listed on [metacpan Date::Manip](https://metacpan.org/search?q=Date%3A%3AManip), and I observe similar things when trying to upgrade it.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I'm a Perl novice, but does this mean there's something at the source that could be causing this?

Comment: It's a problem with the distribution: https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=96459  Try installing an earlier version by specifying an earlier tarball URI on your `cpanm` command line.

Comment: I cannot seem to locate previous versions. They all seem to have been pulled?

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/S/SB/SBECK/Date-Manip-5.56.tar.gz

Comment: How about grabbing a 2010 version from github/gitpan? https://github.com/gitpan/Date-Manip

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same problem today.

I've been able to get 6.44 installed by doing the following from within the cpan cli (you can access this by simply typing cpan in your terminal).

The developer for Date::Manip has archived previous versions of the module, you'll need to add the backpan URL into your cpan config so you can search for it.

```
o conf urllist push http://backpan.perl.org/
```

Now you should be able to install using a direct path to version 6.44

```
install SBECK/Date-Manip-6.44.tar.gz
```

I had to accept that the checksum wasn't present in the package, but after that the module seemed to install correctly.

I suspect you'll want to keep an eye on the module and [this bug report](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=96459) so that you can upgrade once it has been fixed.

Comment: Thank you Dan! This got me up & running!

Comment: FInally a solution worked even in 2022

Answer (score 1):

`perl -MCPAN -e "install 'SBECK/Date-Manip-6.44.tar.gz'"`

or wait until the distribution is fixed. `'.#Changes6.pod'` is an illegal filename for your tar.